React: update state-object which properties are dependent on another
I have created a state-object
const [tableStates, setTableStates] = useState<TableStates>({
currentPage: 1,
indexOfLastItem: indexOfLastItem,
indexOfFirstItem: indexOfFirstItem,
currentItems: props.data.slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem),
  })

Now I want to update this state-object while its properties are dependent on each other:
setTableStates({
  ...tableStates,
  indexOfLastItem: tableStates.currentPage * itemsPerPage,
  indexOfFirstItem: tableStates.indexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage < 0 ? 0 : tableStates.indexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage,
  currentItems: props.data.slice(tableStates.indexOfFirstItem, tableStates.indexOfLastItem),
})

However that does not work. While the first property is updated all other properties are not. How do I fix that?
I tried creating states for each variable and update the states sequentially, but it was not successfull. Somebody told me to create a state-object. What is the right way to implement such a state-object with dependent states?

In this line
indexOfFirstItem: tableStates.indexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage < 0 ? 0 : tableStates.indexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage,

you are trying to use tableStates.indexOfLastItem value to calculate indexOfFirstItem value, But tableStates.indexOfLastItem refers to it's previous value,Not the new one you set in it's above line.
You can do this instead :
const newIndexOfLastItem = tableStates.currentPage * itemsPerPage
const newIndexOfFirstItem = newIndexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage < 0 ? 0 : newIndexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage
setTableStates({
  ...tableStates,
  indexOfLastItem: newIndexOfLastItem,
  indexOfFirstItem: newIndexOfFirstItem,
  currentItems: props.data.slice(newIndexOfFirstItem, newIndexOfLastItem),
})

